# Linker command failed with exit code 1 - Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, facebook-graph-api, xcode7

I am trying to archive my app but every time I try I get an error:

```
ld: '/Users/Omer/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginCompletion.o)' does not contain bitcode. 
You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Enable Bitcode is set to YES but I still get this error.

What causes it and how can I fix it?

UPDATE

I have set Enable Bitcode to NO but now I get even more errors:

http://postimg.org/image/rqt1m35fx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will occur in many scenario

**Choice -1**

> Check that all your bundle resources are copied in build phase

**Choice-2**

> It turned out that all related framework for Google are added or not

**Choice-3**

> Check that all your bundle resources are copied in build phase

**Choice-4**

if you are using `cocoapods` make sure your target's `build settings` contain `$(inherited)` in the `other linker flags` section

**Choice-5**

You can get this type of error if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources" step of the "Build Phases" tab of your target.  sometimes it loses the plot and you need to add the .m file manually.

> Preoject TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class  ->Build and Run

**Choice-6**

> Normally we add the library of the imported project in Target Dependency in Build Phases but we forget to add "compiled library" in Link Binary with Libraries in Build Phases

Answer (score 1):

Set it as `NO` because as error says `/Users/Omer/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit(FBSDKLoginCompletion.o)' does not contain bitcode.`

Comment: Are you using latest Facebook SDK?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version

Comment: Just remove old SDK and download new SDK again and add it.

Comment: I downloaded the last version of the Facebook SDK today

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My answer is 
1.Right-click on the error message-->reavel in log . 
2.Look at the error message. Find file name. 
3.Find file name in your project. 
4.After finding delete it Run again or archive again. 
That‘s my solution. This is a headache question. I hope to help you;

Answer (score -1):

Your options are to either:

1. Disable bit code for the project
2. Update to the latest Facebook SDK which has bit code support